# what is the c++ equivalent type if MPI_FLOAT_INT

Tags: c++, mpi

I am writing a type_traits library for mpi, but when I define `float int` as a type for `MPI_FLOAT_INT`, I get two or more variable type in declaration error, what is the equivalent type of `MPI_FLOAT_INT` in c++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only authoritative source, the [MPI standard](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf), defines `MPI_FLOAT_INT` as (Section 5.9.4 *`MINLOC` and `MAXLOC`*):

> The datatype `MPI_FLOAT_INT` is *as if* defined by the following sequence of instructions.

```
type[0] = MPI_FLOAT
type[1] = MPI_INT
disp[0] = 0
disp[1] = sizeof(float)
block[0] = 1
block[1] = 1
MPI_TYPE_CREATE_STRUCT(2, block, disp, type, MPI_FLOAT_INT)
```

> Similar statements apply for `MPI_LONG_INT` and `MPI_DOUBLE_INT`.

It means that the type corresponds to `struct { float a; int b; }`, but only if there is guarantee that no padding space is inserted between `a` and `b`. This might not be the case on systems where `int` is 64-bit and has to be aligned on 8 bytes. One might need to instruct the compiler to generate packed structures, e.g. with GCC:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct float_int
{
   float a;
   int b;
}
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Note that `MPI_FLOAT_INT` is intended to be used in `MINLOC` and `MAXLOC` reductions in order to find out both the min/max `float` value and the lowest numbered rank that is holding it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://beige.ucs.indiana.edu/I590/node100.html):

> MPI_FLOAT_INT
>     This is a pair of a 32-bit floating point number followed by a 32-bit integer.

An equivalent would be `std::pair<float, int>` or `struct float_int{ float f; int i;};`.

You can try to do a bit better with `int32_t` instead of `int` and `static_assert(sizeof(float) == 4);` in an attempt to get the size correct.

Comment: That is not the official MPI specification. MPI does not the dictate number of bytes in an int or float.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mpi_float_int), `MPI_FLOAT_INT` is a struct defined as:

`struct { float, int }`