# MPI_DOUBLE_INT and C++ struct

Tags: c++, struct, mpi, packing

The [MPI standard](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf) defines a family of data types `MPI_X_INT` with `X = FLOAT, DOUBLE, ...`. Let's stick with `MPI_DOUBLE_INT` for definiteness. Its formal definition is:

> *(p. 180)* The datatype MPI_DOUBLE_INT is as if defined by the following sequence of instructions:
>
> ```
> block[0] = 1;
> block[1] = 1;
> disp[0] = 0;
> disp[1] = sizeof(double);
> type[0] = MPI_DOUBLE;
> type[1] = MPI_INT;
> MPI_TYPE_CREATE_STRUCT(2, block, disp, type, MPI_DOUBLE_INT);
> ```

The definition implies no padding between `double` and `int`. The standard also asserts that the total size of this type should be 16, the example reads (for `char` instead of `int`):

> *(p.85)* **Example 4.1** Assume that `Type = {(double, 0), (char, 8)}` (a `double` at displacement zero, followed by a `char` at displacement eight). Assume, furthermore, that `double`s have to be strictly aligned at addresses that are multiples of eight. Then, the extent of this datatype is 16 (9 rounded to the next multiple of 8).

The corresponding C++ structure is `struct DI { double d; int i; };`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44508948/1625187) asserts that the `struct` should be packed to avoid padding between `double` and `int`. But the size of a packed structure is 12 (assuming `sizeof(int) = 4`), and it is impossible to use an array of them:

```
constexpr auto count = 2;  // >1
DI_packed di[count] = {...};
MPI_Send(di, count, MPI_DOUBLE_INT, ...);  // wrong!
```

Is there a C++ `struct` that corresponds exactly to the MPI definition and that can be safely and portably used in an MPI code? It seems that the only *guaranteed* way to use `struct` is to define a packed structure with manually added tail padding `char`s. Is this correct?

As a side note, on my machine both MSVC and GCC generate the "MPI-compatible" layout for unpacked `struct DI`, so this question might be irrelevant from a practical point of view, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can do this using *union*?

If you compile the following with g++ and run

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  typedef struct {double x; int i;} Tmp;
  typedef union {char pad[16]; Tmp dint;} Doubleint;

  Doubleint value;

  value.dint.x = 3.14;
  value.dint.i = 6;

  cout << "sizeof(Tmp)       = " << sizeof(Tmp)       << endl;
  cout << "sizeof(Doubleint) = " << sizeof(Doubleint) << endl;

  typedef struct {double x; int i;} __attribute__((packed)) Packtmp;
  typedef union {char pad[16]; Packtmp dint;} Packdoubleint;

  Packdoubleint packvalue;

  packvalue.dint.x = 6.12;
  packvalue.dint.i = 9;

  cout << "sizeof(Packtmp)       = " << sizeof(Packtmp)       << endl;
  cout << "sizeof(Packdoubleint) = " << sizeof(Packdoubleint) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

you get

```
sizeof(Tmp)       = 16
sizeof(Doubleint) = 16
sizeof(Packtmp)       = 12
sizeof(Packdoubleint) = 16
```

i.e. the union variables (Doubleint and Packdoubleint) are always 16 bytes long even if the structures have different sizes - I've forced Packtmp to be unpadded using an attribute specific to g++.

Answer (score 0):

You might use [C++11's alignas keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) to fix alignment ([gcc 9.2](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/_ZopRg),[clang 9.0.0](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WUhDTq),[icc 19.0.1](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3-N-xG)):

```
 int main() {
    #pragma pack(push, 1)
    struct alignas(alignof(double)) pair {
        double d;
        int i;
    };
    #pragma pack(pop)

    static_assert(sizeof(double) == 8, "");
    static_assert(sizeof(int) == 4, "");
    static_assert(sizeof(double)+sizeof(int) == 12, "");
    static_assert(sizeof(pair) == 16, "");
    static_assert(alignof(double) == 8, "");
    static_assert(alignof(pair) == 8, "");

    return 0;
}
```

Without `alignas` the packed struct has alignment issues on x86-64 linux with [gcc 9.2](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/239vBP), [clang 9.0.0](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/m4guVL) and [icc 19.0.1](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5PzG55):

```
 int main() {
     #pragma pack(push, 1)
     struct pair {
         double d;
         int i;
     };
     #pragma pack(pop)

     static_assert(sizeof(double) == 8, "");
     static_assert(sizeof(int) == 4, "");
     static_assert(sizeof(double)+sizeof(int) == 12, "");
     static_assert(sizeof(pair) == 12, "");
     static_assert(alignof(double) == 8, "");
     static_assert(alignof(pair) == 1, ""); // !!!

     return 0;
 }
```

BTW: Not sure, but OpenMPI might be able to handle non-packed structs during datatype definition in [ompi/datatype/ompi_datatype_module.c](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/blob/master/ompi/datatype/ompi_datatype_module.c):

```
 #define DECLARE_MPI2_COMPOSED_STRUCT_DDT( PDATA, MPIDDT, MPIDDTNAME, type1, type2, MPIType1, MPIType2, FLAGS) \
     do {                                                                             \
         struct { type1 v1; type2 v2; } s[2];                                         \
         ompi_datatype_t *types[2], *ptype;                                           \
         int bLength[2] = {1, 1};                                                     \
         ptrdiff_t base, displ[2];                                                    \
                                                                                      \
         types[0] = (ompi_datatype_t*)ompi_datatype_basicDatatypes[MPIType1];         \
         types[1] = (ompi_datatype_t*)ompi_datatype_basicDatatypes[MPIType2];         \
         base = (ptrdiff_t)(&(s[0]));                                                 \
         displ[0] = (ptrdiff_t)(&(s[0].v1));                                          \
         displ[0] -= base;                                                            \
         displ[1] = (ptrdiff_t)(&(s[0].v2));                                          \
         displ[1] -= base;                                                            \
                                                                                      \
         ompi_datatype_create_struct( 2, bLength, displ, types, &ptype );             \
         displ[0] = (ptrdiff_t)(&(s[1]));                                             \
         displ[0] -= base;                                                            \
         if( displ[0] != (displ[1] + (ptrdiff_t)sizeof(type2)) )                      \
             ptype->super.ub = displ[0];                                              \
         ...
```